# Newbie, tracing/understanding transactions

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, transaction-data

Am I correct?
I see in my transaction "From Block" these things:
Hash    IDon'tKnowIfIShouldObscureThis
Height  1317365 (437 confirmations)
Timestamp (UTC) 2017-05-24 18:40:59 (15 hours ago)

In my Full node Monero Wallet I see:
Synced 1238883/1288639

Does this mean:
1: I have to wait untill synced Synced 1288639/1288639
2: Then wait untill I get 1317365
before I can see the money in my balance?

(balance is still 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see in my transaction "From Block" these things:
>   Hash IDon'tKnowIfIShouldObscureThis
>   Height 1317365 (437 confirmations)
>
> In my Full node Monero Wallet I see: Synced 1238883/1288639
>
> Does this mean I have to wait until I get 1317365
>   before I can see the money in my balance?

You are correct. Until you have synced up the the block height of your incoming transaction your wallet will be unaware of it.

With Monero there is no way to look up the [balance of an address](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/93/why-are-rich-lists-impossible-to-create-for-monero). Instead every block is scanned to see if it contains any outputs which your wallet controls. In your case the block in question will not been seen until you sync to height 1317365