# Does publishing view key and key images give the auditor the information on where I sent the funds?

Tags: wallet-recovery, viewkey, stealth-address, auditing, key-image

I see [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8/how-can-a-business-or-charity-publish-proof-of-xmr-reserves) that it's possible to provide information to an auditor to prove the balance at a certain point in time (block height). Would this tell the auditor to where were the funds were sent? Based on my understanding, the answer should be no - is it because the addresses themselves don't appear anywhere on the blockchain and stealth addresses are used?

Consequentially, is it correct to assert that if I lose my wallet file, I also lose the history of destination addresses? If I would later recover my wallet from keys (or seed) and re-scan the blockchain, I would be able to see only that the input has been spent, and the related payment ID of the tx, but not the address of the recipient, as it's not recorded on the blockchain due to stealth addresses being used as destination.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the auditor wanted to confirm you had sent funds to a specific address, they'll then need to have the view key of that address also. The only thing the view key of your address can determine which outputs were sent to its corresponding public key. The key images can confirm when a transaction took place, and how much was was moved from your address. It can't verify who you sent it to, or who you received it from.

Comment: so having my view key and all key images and just knowing the destination address wouldn't be enough to assert that the funds were sent to it? Care to elaborate on why is that so?

Comment: You only need to reveal the key for that specific transaction, which both the sender and receiver have.

Comment: You'd still need some info from the receiver to fully verify the contents of the transaction, on your end you could prove when, your authorisation/receiving of funds and the amount, but you can't make a connection to the other party's address unless they provide the last bit of info, https://xmr.llcoins.net/ allows you to piece all this info together so it's easier to understand, but it's down right now.

Answer (score 5):

It is impossible to calculate what the address is that corresponds to a given one-time address (there are actually multiple possibility). It is possible to check if a transaction corresponds to a given address.

An auditor would need both your outgoing tx keys, and an address book to figure out where the funds are going.

Answer (score 4):

In monero transactions every output is sent to a One-Time Public Key (stealth address), which is derived from the recipient Public Key, the position or index of the output in the transaction and a random number generated by the sender. As ferretinjapan explained, only the receiver may check if that One-Time Key is derived from his Public Key.