# I have public address and private view key. How can I check ballance online?

Tags: viewkey, block-explorer

I have public Monero address and private view key. How can I check how many XMR is currently on the address, without installing anything?

I am looking for some equivalent of blockchain.info that can be used to validate that address received some bitcoins.

I dont have transaction id. I cant install wallet locally.

Thanks.

Comment: Question closed as duplicate. Note that more functionality is available if you can install a local wallet and daemon: http://monero.stackexchange.com/a/22/7